# Interactive menu based exe in Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, exe

I have a win32 exe which I want to execute using a Python script. The win32 is interactive in nature, i.e it requires a few user inputs to be passed after I run the application. Can this be done using Python? I know a way of doing it in Java, but if I can do it in Python it would be ideal. So if anyone has been able to do something similar, please let me know.

Comment: Does the exe file take command line parameters?

Comment: Nope the exe file does not take Command Line args, its a menu kind of application, so first screen it loads 7 options and then it expects the user to input a number 1-7, and then based on that subsequent menus are loaded. Thanks!

Comment: Not enough detail yet. What automation mechanisms are exposed by this program?

Comment: Unfortunately no automation mechanisms are exposed by this program, it has been typically used by user interaction. Here is an example scenario:

C:> execute.exe
Choose one of the following options:
1. Upload file 2. Download File 3. Create New File 4. Delete File 5. FTP To remote location 6. Compress File
Choose [1-6] : 

After the above options are shown, user will choose 3 for example and a corresponding submenu is shown to the user. I want to automate this using a python script. hope that makes a clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to run exe use python.

1. os.system
2. os.popen
3. subprocess.popen

eg:

```
import os 
os.popen("youEXE.exe arg1 arg2")
```

Comment: It's worth saying which is the preferred method and why.

Comment: @yrhsilence : the application does not accept command line arguments, it is an interactive menu driven application where the user will key in the options, is there any way I can automate this using Python. Thanks!